# How to fetch the whole string using regexp_substr(Oracle) with just condition for the starting character

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I need to just mention the starting character of a string and get the remaining part of the string as output using regexp_substr.

If it is possible, please share how to do it.

For example,

```
select 
    REGEXP_SUBSTR('500 Oracle Parkway, Redwood Shores, CA','P[[:alpha:]]{6}', 1, 1,'i') 
from dual;
```

The above query returns '**Parkway**' as the output.

To get '**Parkway, Redwood Shores, CA**' as the output, what is the query?
But I need a generic query so that whatever the string might be, it is supposed to return the whole string after 'P'(including 'P').

Comment: replace the `[[:alpha:]]{6}` with `.*`?

Comment: @KevinEsche Thanks a lot. Works as expected